# How to downsample data in AWS TimeStream

Tags: time-series, amazon-timestream

I understand AWS TimeStream allows data to be moved to different types of storage based on retention period but we also need data to be downsampled based on retention period.

For e.g.

- 48 hours, one second granularity
- 30 days, one minute granularity
- 10 years, one hour granularity

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `timestream` currently supports that in storage. The nature of time-series databases is that you write once & change very very seldom. So by the intention behind it, this kind of granularity change you'd do in the query with for example the [`bin()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/date-time-functions.html) function.

Comment: That's a pity because if the original incentive for the granularity change was to reduce data size for cost reasons, doing it in the query only doesn't help at all (the whole unreduced data stays in the DB and produces cost).  The only option I see to achieve this is by storing several versions of the same data in the first place, with different granularity and different retention times each.